# What is wrong with this operator being undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that has the following lines in the ngOnInit method

```
    this.businessTypesService.get()
        .subscribe((businessTypes: string[]) => {
            _.each(businessTypes,
                (businessType: string) => {
                    this.businessTypes.push({ label: businessType, value: businessType });
                });
        });
```

Now I have this same type of block 10 times each loading different drop lists of options.  Each is the same except for which service it calls and which array it pushes the results into, so I want to refactor this into a single method, so that I can change the code to something like this.

```
this.loadReferenceList(this.businessTypesService.get, this.businessTypes);
```

and the new loadReferenceList method looks like this

```
loadReferenceList(loadMethod: () => Observable<string[]>, lookupList: SelectItem[]): any {
    loadMethod()
        .subscribe(((items: string[]) => {
            _.each(items,
                (item: string) => {
                    lookupList.push({ label: item, value: item });
                });
        }));
}
```

Each of the service classes look like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BusinessUnitsService {

    get(): Observable<string[]> {
        return Observable.of(this.getData());
    }

    constructor(private readonly http: Http) { }

    getData(): string[] {
        return [
            'Beverage',
            'Food',
            'Beverage & Food',
            'Promo Pack'
        ];
    }

}
```

Right now it is just hard coded data, but will be changed to use Http to pull down the real values later.

The problem is that the this.getdata() line is failing saying that this is undefined.  I don't understand why this would be undefined when I change it around to be called like this.

********Answer************
I made the following changes to get this to work based off of the answer below
the loadReferenceList method was changed to look like this.  Basically added a parameter for the service, so that I could have a reference to what this was supposed to be and then added the .bind method to give the method scope.

```
loadReferenceList(loadMethod: () => Observable<string[]>, service: any, lookupList: SelectItem[]): any {
    const method = loadMethod.bind(service);

    method()
        .subscribe(((items: string[]) => {
            _.each(items,
                (item: string) => {
                    lookupList.push({ label: item, value: item });
                });
        }));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to bind your .get() to your object, i.e.

`loadReferenceList(this.businessTypesService.get.bind(this.businessTypesServices), ...)`

or you need to define abstract interface for all services and pass objects as is

`loadReferenceList(service: AbstractService, ...) {
     service.get()
}`

all your services need to implement this interface

Comment: That doesn't work because this is undefined.  So this.getData errors, therefore this.getData.bind will error as well.

Comment: did you try or you're speculating about the comment?

Comment: Both. I knew it wouldn't work and I tried it for you just to make sure

Comment: ok, looking into code more precisely I still see my proposal is correct, but in other place. You need to bind you .get() function to the object. Otherwise you pass just function and nothing more.

Comment: Thank you I editted the question with my final changes based off of what you said

Answer (score 0):

[I made a live simple version of what you're doing](https://embed.plnkr.co/av2ilzuRQt2WNVWCWLQ0/).

I was having problems using Observable.of(...). It worked when i used Observable.create(...) and new Observable(...).

With pretty much anything that has to do with rxjs, I use a plunkr like this to test. Let me know if it helps?

Comment: I don't see you using the this operator in your example.  I tried doing it with a new observable anyway, but I still get undefined when I do observer.next(this.getData());

Comment: My apologies, the plunkr was reset when i embedded it.